# Sharing screenshot on windows phone in unity

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to share a screenshot on unity for windows phone using ShareMediaTask  class in windows phone? as I dont want to have app authentication I just want to open the share task .

Answer (score 1):

1. Save screenshot in Unity using Texture2D.ReadPixels()
2. Then Texture2D.EncodeToPNG() and save the File in local storage
3. Create an event to be implemented on native side (Visual Studio) and invoke it in Unity
4. Build Unity project to generate Visual Studio project and implement the event there - access the stored png file and share it.

Source: [Unity interaction with Windows Phone](http://docs.unity3d.com/510/Documentation/Manual/wp8-unity-interaction.html)